# React-i18next in micro-frontend

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, micro-frontend

I've built a react app with react-i18next for localization. But when I use it as a micro-frontend in another app, it's not translating the text and returning json keys. Do I need to use i18next localization for parent/host app also or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/788 https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/726

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file with the translation keys is in the orchestrated one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do domething like this: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react-component-lib/src/i18n.js

use the provider: https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider#when-to-use